# Security configure http with database type=Forbidden, status=403

Tags: java, database, spring, security, configuration

I am trying to configure SecurityConfig with method configure(HttpSecurity http). I am using entities for user and role for database . It's look good I am able to add one USER and one ADMIN.

To configure it I had to use `UserDetailsService`that takes information from database. It seems to work with open pages, and pages with authorization for all. But when i want to add page only for ADMIN, I have error

`type=Forbidden, status=403`.

I was looking for answer at stack and I add some annotations like:

`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")` but it still does not work. I hope it is small mistake but after few days of work I do not have any idea where to look . Any Help is highly appreciated.

These are my Classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", 
                 "/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();

       }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

}

@RestController
public class SimpleHelloController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello there admin";
    }
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long role_id;
    private String role;
}

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long user_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);

        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = null;

        if(user != null){

            customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
            customUserDetails.setUser(user);

        }else{
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not exist");
        }

        return customUserDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your CustomUserDetails class. You create the SimpleGrantedAuthority with the role object, not the role object's role name. The getAuthorities method should look something like this:

```
...
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
...
```

Comment: Now it is clear - simple mistake. Thank you very much +1